# MySQL trigger syntax error near CREATE TRIGGER

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, delimiter

I'm trying to create trigger in Mysql, and get the error:

```
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to  use near 'CREATE TRIGGER `foo`.`test` AFTER INSERT ON `foo`.`test` FOR EACH ROW BE' at line 2
```

in this trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
SET @name2:='w';
CREATE TRIGGER `foo`.`test`
AFTER INSERT
    ON `foo`.`test`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SELECT name1 INTO name2;
    END;
    $$
DELIMITER ;
```

What is wrong with line 2?

Comment: With `DELIMITER $$` you change the delimiter and you have to use `$$` then to end every statement. But you use `;` instead in the next line. And setting a variable outside the trigger does not make sense.

Comment: removing ; does no better - same error

Comment: Don't remove it. Replace it with `$$`. But the next line, as I already said, does not make sense anyway. I guess you don't understand what a trigger is. Read about it first. You probably want a *Stored Procedure* instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
  DELIMITER $$

 CREATE TRIGGER `foo`.`test` AFTER INSERT
ON `foo`.`test`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SET @name2:='w';
SELECT name1 INTO @name2;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Undeclared variable: name2